# Java File Encryption AES

Tags: java, file, cryptography, aes

**PROBLEM:** Upload method is working the problem I'm presenting is `**encrypt(inputFile, new  File("Users/myname/Desktop/example.txt"),key);**` instead of writing to my desktop I want it to be stored as a file or var I can use so I can upload to dropbox server. I just do not know how to code this part and do not know what to put so this will execute appropriately.

```
    private byte[] getKeyBytes(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(key.length, keyBytes.length));
            return keyBytes;
        }

        public Cipher getCipherEncrypt(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
            byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            return cipher;
        }

        public void encrypt(File in, File output, byte[] key) throws Exception {

            Cipher cipher = getCipherEncrypt(key);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            CipherOutputStream cos = null;
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(in);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
                cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int read = fis.read(data);
                while (read != -1) {
                    cos.write(data, 0, read);
                    read = fis.read(data);
                   System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());

                }
                cos.flush();
                System.out.println("name"+ output);


            } finally {
                System.out.println("performed encrypt method now closing streams");
                cos.close();
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
        }




    // Working Upload Method To DropBox Cloud
    public void uploadFile () throws DbxException, IOException, FileLoadException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidParameterSpecException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException, ShortBufferException, Exception {

    // autheticate if there is a accessToken here if not prompt to login by activating the drop method re-auth..
    try{
      phoneHome();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("not saving accessToken");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Access Information Does Not Exist,\n Please Login"+
    "Please Login By Clicking 'OK'"); 
     drop(); // will run auth method for user to login
    }

    // user picks file to upload with JFileChooser
     fc = new JFileChooser();
     fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
     fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    int dialog = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
     if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

       inputFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
       inputFile.getName();
       inputFile.getAbsoluteFile();
        String nameOf = inputFile.getName();
        System.out.println(" File: " + inputFile);


    /* calling out inputFIle from out JFileChooser and now passing it into
        our method and encrytping and outputing it.
        */


    encrypt(inputFile, new  File("Users/myname/Desktop/example.txt"),key);



    File selected = new File ("?");
    inputStream = new FileInputStream (selected);
    uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +selected ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);

    /*
Original works without encryption 
    File selectedFile = new File(nameOf+inputFile);
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    */


    // Original  uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +selectedFile ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);



    setTitle("Uploading File..");
    System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Upload:" + uploadedFile.toString(),
            "Success!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: It seems your question is "How to upload a file to dropbox?", but then your title has nothing to do with that question and the tags are also no helpful. Is this really your question? If so, then please remove the unnecessary mention of crypto, because your question doesn't seem to be about crypto.

Comment: Agreed. It would possibly be interesting to directly write a stream to dropbox, but moving a pre-generated file has nothing to do with crypto.

Comment: the method uploadFile will accomplish the task of uploading alone by itself. My question is; How do I replace ("users/myname/Desktop/exampme.txt") with a var or a file that I can use to upload? The encrypt method itself is working fine, I just don't want it to write to my desktop I want it to be stored as a file or something I can use to upload etc. in this context,

Answer (score 0):

Solved... all it was is simply over complicating something that didn't need to be complicated furthermore and have settled for a more simplicit way.

```
ORIGINAL:    encrypt(inputFile, new  File("Users/myname/Desktop/example.txt"),key);


   WORKING:    encrypt(inputFile, new  File(inputFile.getName),key);
```

Eazy Peezy... if anyone has any other suggestions I would like to hear them, thanks.